# Programa con decimales en while

Tags: java-8

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
package while2;    
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class While2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numero;
        int i=1;
        int suma=0;
        int TotalNumeros=3;
        double promedio= 0;

        while(i<=TotalNumeros) {
            numero= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Ingresa el numero"));
            suma= numero+suma;
            i=i+1;      
        }

       promedio= suma/TotalNumeros;         
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El valor total de la suma es: " + suma);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El promedio es:" + promedio);        
    }    
}
```

El problema es que el promedio no calcula los decimales.

Ejemplo: si la respuesta es `8` el promedio me da=`2.0` lo hice en Excel y me da `2,666666667`.

Comment: Probaste leer dobles en vez de enteros??, algo como: `double numero; numero= Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Ingresa el numero"));`

Comment: HUY SI AMIGO AHORA SI ME FUNCIONO JUAN PINZON MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: @PupoXws por favor, [no uses mayúsculas](https://www.google.com.co/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=porque%20no%20usar%20mayusculas%20en%20internet).

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español y felicitaciones por animarte a hacer tu primera pregunta @PupoXws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es sencillo, estás utilizando variables `Integer` para realizar el promedio y cómo tales los `Integer` no tienen decimales.

Hay varias opciones pero la más fácil y directa que se acopla a tu pregunta sería utilizar un `Double` que sí que se guarda los decimales.

Simplemente sustituye tu línea con `Integer` por:

```
numero = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Ingresa el numero"));
```

Y declarando el número `numero` como `Double`:

```
double numero;
```

Por lo que tu código final quedaría:

```
package while2;    
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class While2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            double numero;
            double i=1;
            double suma=0;
            double TotalNumeros=3;
            double promedio= 0;

            while(i<=TotalNumeros) {
                double numero; numero= Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Ingresa el numero"));
                suma= numero+suma;
                i=i+1;      
            }

           promedio= suma/TotalNumeros;         
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El valor total de la suma es: " + suma);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El promedio es:" + promedio);        
    }    
}
```